# How to exclude self when iterating over arguments in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iterator

I am trying to graph multiple lines at once (using pyqtgraph). To do so, I have written a method **display**, that has arbitrary number of input arguments. What I want to do is to iterate over these arguments (that are lists), load them into a list (**x_axis**) and then construct a graph from all items on the list. This is (part of) my code:

```
class array():
    def display(self, *args):       # Display all graphs in one window
        """
            @param *args: numpy arrays
        """
        x_axis = []
        y_axis = np.arange(1000)
        for np_array in args:
            x_axis.append(np_array)
        plotWidget = pg.plot(title="min/max/avg graph")
        for i in x_axis:
            plotWidget.plot(y_axis, x_axis[i], pen=(i,3))
```

And I call the **display** method like this:

```
    array.display(self, min_bucket, max_bucket, avg_bucket)
```

The problem is that the **self** argument also gets loaded as an object. Is there a way to exclude **self** from loading into **x_axis**? Or is there a better way to do this?

I am using Python 3.6

Comment: `for np_array in args[1:]`:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not pass `self` when you call the method.  Python handles passing `self` to bound methods behind the scenes.  Your line:

`array.display(self, min_bucket, max_bucket, avg_bucket)`

Should be:

`array.display(min_bucket, max_bucket, avg_bucket)`